# how is a value returned from within a caught exception loop?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, return, try-catch

```js
let traveler = [{
    timestamp: 'qualia',
    firstname: 'unborn',
    lastname: 'child',
    location: 'null'
    },
    {
    timestamp: 1000,
    firstname: 'Olivia',
    lastname: 'Kirshner',
    location: 'Titan'
    },
    {
    timestamp: 1001,
    firstname: 'James',
    lastname: 'Cole',
    location: 'Emerson Hotel'
}]

// function noerror(splinter = traveler[0]) {
//     return [{firstname, lastname}] = splinter
// }

function restructure(time) {
    // if no array is returned on the lookup, and the value flags as undefined in restructure()
    let missingLink = traveler[0]
    let tempArray = traveler
        .filter((item) => item.timestamp === time)
    try {
        if (tempArray.firstname !== 'undefined' || tempArray.firstname !== 'null') { // check does not work
            return [{ firstname, lastname }] = tempArray

        } 
        // else {
        //     return [{firstname, lastname}] = missingLink
        // }
    } catch (e) {
        // e instanceof TypeError // boolean error type check
        switch (e.name) {
            case 'TypeError':
                console.error(`Could not complete your request: ${e.message}`);
                // return [{firstname, lastname}] = missingLink
            default:
                break;
        }
    } 
}

restructure(1001)
console.log(`firstname: ${firstname}, lastname: ${lastname}`)

restructure(100)
console.log(`firstname: ${firstname}, lastname: ${lastname}`)

restructure(1000)
lastname = 'Redforester' // temporary assignment to the variable, by value, not to the Object
console.log(`firstname: ${firstname}, lastname: ${lastname}`)

restructure(1000)
```

Line 42 is giving me a headache.

I'm trying to return a default value from within a caught exception loop when a search key passed to filter produces a blank array.

The error is handled by console.error(), so running the code shows what the error is.

Do you know a method that will allow the default value to be returned from the caught exception loop?

This line has been commented out, but trying it results in a new error:

```
 return [{firstname, lastname}] = missingLink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `filter` returns an array. So, `tempArray`, being an array, doesn't have `firstname` and `lastname` properties.

For this, I suggest you switching `filter()` to `find()` and remove `[]` in your desconstructing:

```js
let traveler = [{
    timestamp: 'qualia',
    firstname: 'unborn',
    lastname: 'child',
    location: 'null'
    },
    {
    timestamp: 1000,
    firstname: 'Olivia',
    lastname: 'Kirshner',
    location: 'Titan'
    },
    {
    timestamp: 1001,
    firstname: 'James',
    lastname: 'Cole',
    location: 'Emerson Hotel'
}]

// function noerror(splinter = traveler[0]) {
//     return [{firstname, lastname}] = splinter
// }

function restructure(time) {
    // if no array is returned on the lookup, and the value flags as undefined in restructure()
    let missingLink = traveler[0]
    let tempArray = traveler
        .find((item) => item.timestamp === time)
    
    try {
        if (tempArray.firstname !== 'undefined' || tempArray.firstname !== 'null') { // check does not work
          return { firstname, lastname } = tempArray

        } 
        // else {
        //     return [{firstname, lastname}] = missingLink
        // }
    } catch (e) {
        // e instanceof TypeError // boolean error type check
        switch (e.name) {
            case 'TypeError':
                console.error(`Could not complete your request: ${e.message}`);
                return {firstname, lastname} = missingLink
            default:
                break;
        }
    } 
}

restructure(1001)
console.log(`firstname: ${firstname}, lastname: ${lastname}`)

restructure(100)
console.log(`firstname: ${firstname}, lastname: ${lastname}`)

restructure(1000)
lastname = 'Redforester' // temporary assignment to the variable, by value, not to the Object
console.log(`firstname: ${firstname}, lastname: ${lastname}`)

restructure(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I believe, the keyword you're searching is `throw`

The `catch(error){}` phrase with catch any `error` thrown in `try{}`.
For example:

```js
   try {
     throw "me"
   }
   catch(error){
     // value of error is "me"
     console.log(error);
   }
```

if you don't throw anything from the `catch`, the propagation stops there.

So, throwing **"us"** will propagate the error to parent function. As such:

```js
   try {
     throw "me"
   }
   catch(error){

     console.log(error);
     // value of error is "me"

     throw "us"
   }
```